# Forward variadic function arguments to another variadic function without cost

Tags: c++, c++11, optimization, variadic-functions, perfect-forwarding

I have a variadic function `LogDebug` for log writing. Logging happens in two modes.
My application forwards variadic arguments to another variadic function `LogDebugEx` in most cases hence that path needs to optimize.
To be specific it takes 38% for `vsnprintf` for some of my requests on callgrind graph. Please note that this function called many times for a single request.

```
void LogDebug(const char* zFormat, ...)
{
    char zDesc[5000];
    va_list ap;
    va_start(ap, zFormat);
    vsnprintf(zDesc, 5000, zFormat, ap);  // Need to optimize in remode mode.
    va_end(ap);

    if (m_logMode == LOG_MODE_LOCAL)    // Does not need to optimize this mode.
    {
        // This mode is not interested.
    }
    else // m_logMode == LOG_MODE_REMOTE, critical path
    {
        LogDebugEx("%s", zDesc);   // Forwarded to new variadic function
    }
}
```

**Question** : I need to avoid copying whole argument list to `zDesc` array before forwarding to `LogDebugEx` function.
Is there a way i can perfect forward variadic arguments coming to `LogDebug` into  `LogDebugEx` function?

Any other fancy way to do this would also be fine without changing function calls to `LogDebug`.
I have `C++11` supported compiler `GCC 4.9.3`.

Comment: Have a `LogDebugExV` function which takes an `va_list` argument? Similar to e.g. `vsprintf` et. al.?

Comment: Also note that you don't "copy" the "whole argument list" now either. All you copy is a *pointer*: `&zDesc[0]`.

Comment: But still takes 38% for `vsnprintf`, even if it does not copy. `LogDebugEx` is a variadic function same as this.

Comment: If you want a string to print somewhere, you sooner or later need to do `vsnprintf` *anyway*. By passing the `va_list` argument to your function you don't have to call `vsnprintf` *twice*, only once in your "extended" function.

Comment: I have no control over `LogDebugEx`. can not change anything there.

Comment: But can you *copy it* to make an `LogDebugExV` function that takes an `va_list` argument?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we have c++11, why mess around with variadic argument lists?

```
#include <utility>

extern enum {LOG_MODE_LOCAL, LOG_MODE_REMOTE} m_logMode;

extern void LogDebugEx(const char*, ...);

template<class...Args>
void LogDebug(const char* zFormat, Args&&...args)
{

    if (m_logMode == LOG_MODE_LOCAL)    // Does not need to optimize this mode.
    {
        char zDesc[5000];
        snprintf(zDesc, 5000, zFormat, args...);  
        // do what you have to do here
    }
    else // m_logMode == LOG_MODE_REMOTE, critical path
    {
        LogDebugEx(zFormat, std::forward<Args>(args)...);   // Forwarded to new variadic function
    }
}
```

Comment: Matched perfectly. I will check my performance with this. Thank you.